# Vertical centering with `position: relative` and `top: 50%`

Tags: css, position

I'm trying to vertically center the `.spinner` element in the following markup ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/t8vJ9/)):

```
<div class=grid>
  <div class=spinner></div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>row 1 cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2 cell 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3 cell 1</td><td>row 3 cell 2</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

With the following styling:

```
.spinner {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

If I set the `.spinner` `top` property to some pixel value, the browser actually positions it according to the value, but if I try to set it to a percentage, it does not work.

**How do I vertically center the `.spinner` element?**

NOTE: I understand I could set the `.grid` position to relative and the `.spinner` position to absolute, but I'd prefer to keep the grid statically positioned. Is this possible without modifiying the `.grid`'s styling?

Comment: In response to your note at the end, no, it's not possible with static positioning of the `.grid` element (unless you add a wrapper within the `.grid` element).

Comment: @bfrohs thnx, you should update your answer w/ that, that's good info!

Comment: I added it to my answer and expanded on it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use `absolute` positioning, with the `.grid` set to `relative` positioning. Then, set `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` to `0` on the `.spinner` element. Since you have a fixed `width`/`height`, the positioning along with `margin:auto;` will center the element perfectly ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/t8vJ9/7/)):

```css
.grid {
    position:relative;
}
.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: red;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

In response to your note at the end, no, it's not possible with static positioning of the `.grid` element (unless you add a wrapper within the `.grid` element). This is because the `.spinner` element has no way of knowing the height dimensions of the table without having a container of some sort with relative positioning (which is where `position:relative;` on the `.grid` element comes in to play). You can work around this with negative margins or relative positioning all you want, but it will never be able to accommodate dynamic content (with the current set of browsers/standards).